# App Insight Alerts - exclude certain http errors or change coding

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have an alert in Application Insights that monitors our app service. The alert looks for request failures greater than 1. It generates a lot of good information and we have eliminated many bugs this way.

Today I used Postman to try to authenticate and made 2 errors and the alert fired, with a 400 exception.

I am not sure how to handle this? This is not really a coding error. Should I exclude 400 errors (is this even possible)? Should the programming handle the http 400 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 0306:**

If you only want to alert on the 2 requests were from a separate API, you can add the where clause with some specified properties, like the name, url etc.(any property can identify the 2 requests.)

For example(if you don't know which property can identify the 2 requests), nav to azure portal -> your application insights -> in the left menu, click Logs -> then double click the **requests** table, and select a proper **Time range**, then click the **Run** button -> in the query results, please check the properties of the 2 requests so you can make sure which property(or properties) can identify the request, screenshot as below:

[image]

if the **name** property can identify the request, just add the where clause like

```
where name == "xxx"
```

if the name and url property combination can identify the request, add below code:

```
| where name == "xxx" 
| where url == "xxx"
```

---

**Original answer:**

There're 2 ways for this.

1.Change the query of alert, add the following `where clause` in the alert query:

```
where resultCode != "400"
```

2.If it's .NET core / .NET framework project, you can use [ITelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering) to filter out the requests whose response code is 400:

Follow this example [Filter out requests with a "401" response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#failed-authentication), and the follow **step 2** in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c) to register the `ITelemetryProcessor`.

Comment: Ivan, this is very helpful, one follow up question. Over the last 30 days I have 33 http 400 errors, 31 of which are for the login API which I don't want to track, but 2 others were from a separate API which I do want to track. Can I add to the where clause so that it is for a resultCode and a particular API?

Comment: it is very helpful. I have accepted this answer. Thank you.